# OpenGL - Is there a way to track actually used memory allocated by glBufferData / glBufferSubData?

Tags: opengl, gpu, nvidia, nsight

There is a big codebase which allocates empty fixed size of GPU memory using glBufferData function, and fills/updates these empty allocated space partially using glBufferSubData. Since not all of the allocated memory is used, is there a way to check how much of the allocated video memory are updated?

Answer (score 0):

Renderdoc shows you how much memory is updated by any of your update methods (`glBufferSubData`, through persistent mapped pointers, etc etc) any time such an update is done (again, very important to track for more transparent update methods like persistent mapped pointers).

Comment: That said, since you're manually updating memory, I'm not sure what you're expecting to see new here. You should know exactly how much memory you're updating for every call of `glBufferSubData`.